# Error trying to get property of non-object from a JSON file with PHP

Tags: php, json

I am trying to get data with php from a JSON file.
This is only one block of data from my JSON... in this JSON file, there is 50 more of so.
Here it is:

```
{
"ConsultarNfseResposta": {
"ListaNfse": {
  "CompNfse": [
    {
      "Nfse": {
        "InfNfse": {
          "Numero": "12651",
          "CodigoVerificacao": "ECSV-EJZZ",
          "DataEmissao": "2017-07-25T17:51:12",
          "NaturezaOperacao": "1",
          "OptanteSimplesNacional": "1",
          "IncentivadorCultural": "2",
          "Competencia": "2017-07-25T00:00:00",
          "Servico": {
            "Valores": {
              "ValorServicos": "2350",
              "IssRetido": "2",
              "BaseCalculo": "2350",
              "Aliquota": "0.02",
              "ValorLiquidoNfse": "2350"
            },
            "ItemListaServico": "0107",
            "CodigoTributacaoMunicipio": "6209100",
            "Discriminacao": "TAXA: SERVIÇO DE VOTAÇÃO ELETRÔNICA",
            "CodigoMunicipio": "2611606"
          },
          "PrestadorServico": {
            "IdentificacaoPrestador": {
              "Cnpj": "41069964000173",
              "InscricaoMunicipal": "2427745"
            },
            "RazaoSocial": "INFORMATICA LTDA",
            "Endereco": {
              "Endereco": "RUA 241",
              "Numero": "241",
              "Bairro": "Exemplo",
              "CodigoMunicipio": "2611606",
              "Uf": "PE",
              "Cep": "52030190"
            },
            "Contato": {
              "Telefone": "33254854",
              "Email": "exemplo@exemplo.com.br"
            }
          },
          "TomadorServico": {
            "IdentificacaoTomador": {
              "CpfCnpj": {
                "Cnpj": "00085803000196"
              }
            },
            "RazaoSocial": "EXEMPLO - AMBR",
            "Endereco": {
              "Endereco": "ST 06",
              "Bairro": "Asa Sul",
              "CodigoMunicipio": "5300108",
              "Uf": "DF",
              "Cep": "15425845211"
            },
            "Contato": {
              "Email": "exemplo@gmail.com"
            }
          },
          "OrgaoGerador": {
            "CodigoMunicipio": "2611606",
            "Uf": "PE"
          }
         }
       }
      }
    ]
   }
  }
 }
```

And here is my php code:

```
<?php

$json = file_get_contents('arquivo.json');

$json_data = json_decode($json,true);

for ($i=0; $i < count($json_data->ConsultarNfseResposta->ListaNfse->CompNfse), $i++;) {

    echo $json_data->ConsultarNfseResposta->ListaNfse->CompNfse[$i]->Nfse->InfNfse->Numero;
    echo $json_data->ConsultarNfseResposta->ListaNfse->CompNfse[$i]->Nfse->InfNfse->CodigoVerificacao;

}

?>
```

I am getting error at line 7: 
**Notice:** Trying to get property of non-object. I've already tried everything and my code isn't working.

What can i do? 
Thanks!

Comment: If you want to figure it out yourself try `var_dump($json_data)` or `var_dump($json_data->ConsultarNfseResposta);` in line 6 before the if statement and compare what you get with `$json_data->ConsultarNfseResposta->ListaNfse->CompNfse` step by step. Hope this is helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter in your `json_decode()` call tells PHP to convert objects to arrays. See [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). You should be fine if you just remove the `true`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer JH, i removed the "true" and the error is gone... but now my echo is returning nothing. Any ideas what is going on? I've tried a few things, but no success.

Answer (score 1):

@FernandoJuriolli, your [for](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) statement isn't right, you have a comma in the wrong place - it should look like this:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($json_data->ConsultarNfseResposta->ListaNfse->CompNfse); $i++) {
```

with the answer from @jh1711, this should work

Comment: Nice find. `,$i++;)` doesn't even throw an error. It just increments $i at the wrong time

Answer (score 0):

Using foreach:

```
$json_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('arquivo.json'));

foreach ($json_data->ConsultarNfseResposta->ListaNfse->CompNfse as $data) {
    echo $data->Nfse->InfNfse->Numero;
    echo $data->Nfse->InfNfse->CodigoVerificacao;
}
```

Comment: you need to change `for` to `foreach` in your code too! :)

Comment: Thank you. I made a mistake.

Comment: Thanks Ramazan and Wee Zel once again! You guys are amazing

Comment: no worries, someone would have downvoted when this is a good answer